# Unit Testing with URLProtocol subclassing returns a 0 bytes Data instead of nil

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, url-scheme

First of all, sorry for my english, I hope it won't be a pain to read me :D

I'm currently building an iOS application for a project in my school and I'm facing a problem.

I make an API call and I test it by using the `URLProtocol` method.

**The API call :**

```
task?.cancel()
task = exchangeSession.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
     // The dataTask method will execute in a separate queue, so we 
     // get back into the main one because
     // we will modify the user interface with our exchange result
     
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
          guard let data = data, error == nil else {
               callback(false, nil, error)
               return
          }
                
          guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
               callback(false, nil, nil)
               return
          }
                
          guard let responseJSON = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ConvertResponse.self, from: data), let result = responseJSON.result else {
               callback(false, nil, nil)
               return
          }
          callback(true, result, nil)
     }
}
task?.resume()
```

**The MockURLProtocol :**

```
final class MockURLProtocol: URLProtocol {
    
    // We return true in order to allow URLSession to use this protocol for any URL Request
    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        return request
    }

    static var loadingHandler: ((URLRequest) -> (Data?, HTTPURLResponse?, Error?))?
    
    override func startLoading() {
        guard let handler = MockURLProtocol.loadingHandler else {
            print("Loading handler is not set.")
            return
        }
        
        let (data, response, error) = handler(request)
        
        guard error == nil else {
            client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error!)
            return
        }
        
        if let data = data {
            client?.urlProtocol(self, didLoad: data)
        }
        
        if let response = response {
            client?.urlProtocol(self, didReceive: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .notAllowed)
        }
        
        client?.urlProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
    }
    
    override func stopLoading() {}
}
```

As you can see, it contains a handler which will have the data / response and error.

In one of my tests I want to check the case where I don't have any data, so I put nil for it.

**The test :**

```
    func testConvertShouldPostFailedCallbackIfNoData() {
        MockURLProtocol.loadingHandler = { request in
            return (nil, nil, nil)
        }
                
        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Wait for queue change.")
        client.convert(from: from, to: to, amount: amount) { success, result, error in
            XCTAssertFalse(success)
            XCTAssertNil(result)
            XCTAssertNil(error)
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
        
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.01)
    }
```

Here is my problem: nil doesn't work for my data parameter, it shows me "0 Bytes" instead.
It works for error and response, which is strange to me.

**The result :** [The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj4db.png)

I wanted to ask you why the data parameter isn't nil?
With 0 bytes it's not considered as nil and I'm not going in the right loop in my code.

*I tried a lot of breakpoints, but I still can't figure it out.
But one thing is really strange. If I put and error in the handler with nil data, the data will be nil.
Maybe it has something to do with the `didFailWithError` function?
This function forces data to be nil somehow?*

Comment: Include code, errors, samples etc as text and not as images. Text is searchable and can be copied into an IDE or similar which makes it easier for those that wants to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry i didn't do well. I edited the post and I hope it's better ! @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0):

`startLoading` is not the right place to check for the response or data or error. Instead, use the `URLSessionDataDelegate`'s delegate methods to check the response/data/error received for that request.